# How RF receivers receive waves with bigger wavelenght than the distance between them?

Tags: radio-frequency

I have a 27MHz RF toy car and I was wondering since the wavelenght is about 11 meters, when the car is closer to the remote than 11 meters how does the car receive the signal? Wouldn't the signal be cut out, only a part of the message being received? And what about waves with higher wavelengths?

Comment: As @JohnForkosh alludes to it you have near zone coupling. My guess is that your toy car has a probably ferrite loaded loop antenna (a coil with a core) and there is a direct magnetic coupling (just as in a magnetic transformer) between that and the transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

In any distance from the transmitter any piece of conducting material will be disturbed in a way, that electrons get displaced.

A radio wave consists of an electric field component and a magnetic field component. Not matter, how close one hold a conductor to the antenna rod,

- the transmitters electric field will accelerate electrons in the conductor mostly parallel to the antenna rod; that is why a receiver *could* include a rod as the receiving antenna
- the transmitters varying magnetic field will induce a Lorentz force in the conductor; that is way a receiver *could* include a loop (open ring).

Furthermore, did you ever ask yourself, why the transmitter has a long antenna rod, but the receiver need a tiny structure only?
The transmitters antenna rod should be tuned to the wave generator, especially its frequency. Otherwise the efficiency of the emitter drops down (but still will emit radio waves).
For the receivers antenna the only requirements are the free flow of electrons (to be a conductor), poles in the right positions to connect the conductor to the electronics and a tuner, which filters out the needed frequency from all the EM radiation, which is around us.

Not to be dependent from theory only, I asked before a question on [Amateur radio stack exchange](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/12514/13834) (commas are from me for better readability):

> It is reasonable to generalize that, if two antennas enable communications in their far field, that bringing them within the near field of the other will still allow communications to occur.